# How should we describe a misdiagnosis due to the fact that the correct diagnosis has not yet been discovered?

Tags: expressions

Respected members
I am a primary care pediatrician from South India, with 31 years experience after my graduation and 26 yeas after MD. Primary care rests on three pillars. Equity,(not equality), community participation and intersectoral coordination. The last one landed me here.

Medicine is an ever changing science, and, when new evidence arises, we 
incorporate it into our daily practice. Classic example will be Vitamin D deficiency. The last decade has expanded  the role of this vitamin in health and disease. Surprisingly, sunlight does not always provide the vitamin, contrary to our thinking in the last century. The prevalence of the deficiency ranges from 50 to 90%, depending upon the area chosen in India. Many countries recommend the vitamin from birth.

All along this vitamin D deficiency was present. It is only now that we can correctly diagnose it, and we have been, increasingly.

That means if the patient had a complaint that arose from vitamin D deficiency, 25 years back 2 things would have been done

- error of omission: the symptom would have been dismissed as trivial
- error of commission: some other treatment would have been given

Of course, there are several such examples over the past 100 years. 
this in no way to degrade my medical community or myself.

**Is there a word or phrase which describes the following sequence:**

- there is a medical condition
- the patient has symptoms
- the best medical practitioners of the time either ignore the condition or provide useless treatment, because of the state of medical knowledge

I would like a term that could be applied to currently unidentified problems.

Additional Information: Idiopathic is not the word .Idiopathic means, the doctor is sure of the disease but does not know the cause

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Also, could you break up your paragraph into smaller, more easily digestible paragraphs. It's very hard (for me) to read as is.

Comment: Dealing with the paragraphs was easy. A better title might actually have answered the question, which is still not entirely clear.

Comment: @Andrew: *Not **entirely** clear?* Does that imply you have at least *some* idea what OP is asking about? I haven't got a clue!

Comment: @F Well, I think he's asking about a misdiagnosis, which means that my edited title has answered the question: It's a *misdiagnosis.*

Comment: I can't tell if the analogy to inferred but undiscovered chemical elements is particularly apt... It might be throwing me or others off...

Comment: I *think* the OP is wondering if there is a term for a misdiagnosis that is made because, *at the time of diagnosis*, the underlying pathology is/was not understood. E.g., a medieval doctor diagnosing demon possession or something where today we might diagnose schizophrenia. This seems like an interesting question, as we could also use such a term to discuss current diagnoses that might be mistaken because we don't yet know what to look for.

Comment: I tried to clarify the question -- my interpretation was the same as @nedibes.  I took out the paragraph on undiscovered elements.  This reminds me of Rumsfeld's unknown unknowns.

Comment: In the US it's often described a "**$$$$$$**", if you can produce a persuasive csae, that is.

Comment: I think it's called "medicine".  I came to realize that half of the doctors out there are trying to kill you when one of mine prescribed massive doses of vitamin D, leading to a severe kidney stone problem.

Comment: @nedibes - Somewhat related:  Many folks died a couple of centuries back because the "cure-all" at the time was bleeding.  George Washington was treated for epiglottitis by removing three quarts of his blood.  It's very likely that the bleeding killed him, not the throat infection.  (I survived a bout with epiglottitis which was only diagnosed after the fact, even though I saw several docs in a "major medical center" while I was suffering from the condition.)

Comment: I sincerely thank @nedibes for editing the  text and changing the title. comment 3 by him correctly catches my intent in asking the question.Idiopathic means, the doctor is usre of the disease but does not know the cause. ( one professor used to joke: idiotic on the part of the doctor. pathetic on the part of the patient). In vitamin d, medical world did not know that the disease is so prevalent. once again thanks for the discussion

Comment: I sincerely thank @nedibes for editing the  text and changing the title. comment 3 by him correctly catches my intent in asking the question.Idiopathic is not the word.Idiopathic means, the doctor is suree of the disease but does not know the cause. That is why I gave the periodic table question( one professor used to joke: idiotic on the part of the doctor. pathetic on the part of the patient). In vitamin d, medical world did not know that the disease is so prevalent. once again thanks for the discussion

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloodletting), the former practice of *bloodletting* to relieve the patient of "plethoras" is a [pseudoscience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscience).

Answer (score 0):

This sounded interesting and my google (re)search landed me at *idiopathy* :

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiopathy

And then, [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/idiopathic):

> *idiopathic* ‎(not comparable)
>
> (pathology) Of, relating to, or designating a disease or condition
>   having no known cause.

Comment: It seems to me that *idiotpathic* would be more appropriate.  An *idiopathic* disorder is (as you say) one whose cause is unknown.  But many disorders are misdiagnosed or properly diagnosed but inappropriately treated.

Answer (score 0):

*wrongful diagnosis* -> *delayed diagnosis* / <strike>misdiagnoses</strike>

> According to the American Journal of Medicine, each year up to 15 percent of patients suffer needlessly as a result of **wrong diagnoses, which include misdiagnoses and delayed diagnoses**. A wrong diagnosis is considered medical malpractice if the doctor's actions "deviated from the medical standard of care" of similarly trained doctors. ...
>
> Unless a doctor's mistake results in serious injury, the chances of winning a medical malpractice case are small. ...
>
> A misdiagnosis occurs when a doctor fails to recognize symptoms which are **clearly attributable to one illness**, and instead attributes them to another illness. When this occurs, the actual illness may go untreated, resulting in worsening symptoms, and a faster onset of the illness. –[injuryclaimcoach.com](http://www.injuryclaimcoach.com/wrong-diagnosis.html#)

---

***delayed diagnosis***

> Definition: Non-optimal interval of time between onset of symptoms, identification, and initiation of treatment.  –[reference.md](http://www.reference.md/files/D057/mD057210.html)

It's only a *misdiagnosis* when the (real) illness has a known pathology.

It is a *delayed diagnosis* until the illness is "identified" having begun at the "onset of symptoms" and ending with the "initiation of treatment."

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference work. I will share with my friends